# Inaccurate FAQ section about moderator tools

Tags: bug, status-declined, beta, privileges

As reputation requirement is lower on this beta site than in SO site, then not everything on [this page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) is accurate. I'm talking about the section `How many times can I vote to delete per day?`. As requirement here is 2000 reputation, instead 10000, so information about extra votes is inaccurate.

Please correct.

Comment: That stuff really annoys me - it can't be that hard to "variable-ize". I think it changes between private and public beta stages too.

Comment: I'm hoping one of our SE overlords notices this, otherwise, I'll message them on the mod chat room.

Comment: You can also ask on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), as this likely affects all other beta sites in the network.

Comment: good grief, how many things do you want to delete?? Worst case you can msg one of us in the chat room, and if we're around we'll take a look

Comment: Mark, it's not about deletion, I don't have that rep, it's about pointing out inaccuracy

Comment: OK I thought maybe you'd hit a limit or something ;)

Comment: Not wanting people do go wild deleting stuff is no reason to have totally wrong information about the the deletion features.

Answer (score 4):

Closing this bug as not applicable anymore.